# What does "In keeping with the rationale of reconciling..." mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Excerpt:

> **In keeping with the rationale of** reconciling environmental protection, economic development and the fight against poverty in a sustainable manner, as formulated by the United Nations in 1992 at the “Earth Summit” of Rio de Janeiro and expressed in Agenda 21, adopted on that occasion, ([from Preamble of the Global Code of Ethics for Tourism](http://dtxtq4w60xqpw.cloudfront.net/sites/all/files/docpdf/gcetbrochureglobalcodeen.pdf))

I understand the bold part as:
we agree to the necessity of reconciling ....

what does *keep with* and *rationale* mean here? *keep with* means pursuing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In Keeping With

`in keeping with` is an idiom and can [mean](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+keeping+with):

> Conforming to, in harmony with, as in *The new wing is in keeping with the house's original architecture*, or *His actions are not in keeping with his words*. **This expression uses keeping in the sense of "harmony,"** as does its antonym, out of keeping with, as in *The funeral arrangements were out of keeping with the family's wishes*.

in keeping with something:

> 1. **because of something**: There will be no flowers at the funeral, in keeping with the family's wishes.
> 2. **suited to something**: The new windows are in keeping with the colonial style of the house.

#### Rationale

As to `rationale` the noun — which isn't the same as `rational` the adjective — it means:

> a set of reasons or a logical basis for a course of action or a particular belief.

#### 1 + 1

The emphasized part in your quote means: "Conforming to/Acting upon the belief (or set of beliefs) that we should once again act with the enviroment in mind..."

Comment: gr8, what do you mean by 1+1?

Comment: Well, if we *combine* (add) what I wrote about "In Keeping With" and "Rationale", we can deduce what the phrase means in its entirety.